# Maven show JAR inclusion error and doesn't run selenium acceptance test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

### I'm trying to build this (https://github.com/wakaleo/game-of-life) Java project using maven, and run acceptance test using it. but it shows test result as run 0: I followed all the instruction mentioned in readme file

```
cd gameoflife-acceptance-tests
mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=firefox -Dwebdriver.base.url=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/gameoflife
```

---

```
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

---

As I'm running this project on centos, I had installed xvfb from this site http://www.jpalomaki.fi/?p=403 and added following content in pom.xml file because it was giving Firefox driver error:

File: gameoflife-acceptance-tests/pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

It also show the following JAR inclusion error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ gameoflife-acceptance-tests ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /data/jenkins_demo/gameoflife-acceptance-tests/target/gameoflife-acceptance-tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

---

```
[root@gameoflife-acceptance-tests]# mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jar inclusion error is there because there is no code being compiled and put into a jar.  This is expected, there is no src/main/* in the acceptance tests sub module.

Looking at the POM it is either expecting:

1. You have a copy of game-of-life running locally.
2. You to specify a profile which will set the URL where game-of-life is running.

The available profiles in the POM are:

- development
- integration
- staging
- production

To select a profile you would need to run:

```
mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
```

The profiles will not help you if you don't have access to these environment (which I would guess you don't)

Comment: I have access to this environment,  I have modified the pom.xml and put the same URL in all profiles. but still it shows 

Results :

    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!

Comment: Are you running game of life at the URL you have entered in all the profiles?  Have you specified a profile to use?  None of the profiles are marked as active by default so they will be ignored if you don't specify them.